# Capture click on a leaflet bindpopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

How to capture the "on click" event on a leaflet bindpopup? I am trying to load data on the popup from a database. Thus, I want to call a function when the marker is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you're trying to do. It may be that you're looking for the `popupopen` event but take a look at [the documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events)

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.latlng);
});
```